# Unity- UI, Changing color of an image, causes it to resize, taking up the entire screen

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab that I import with

```
GameObject imagePrefab = Resources.Load("demonSkull") as GameObject;
image = GameObject.Instantiate(imagePrefab, imagePrefab.transform.position, imagePrefab.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
image.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("BattleCanvas").transform, false);
```

It appears on the screen just fine.

However, Later on I try to set its color with:

```
GameObject.Find("Foo").GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

For some weird reason, it doesn't change the color. Instead, the image expands to take up the entire screen.

Unity doesn't throw an error.

Any idea of what's causing this?

Comment: You are making the image completly transparent. Maybe there is another image behind that is big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the material.color

Generic:

gameObject.GetComponent ().material.color = Color.green;